# What is the difference in behavior between 1.0*a/b and (float)a/b when performing division in a simple calculator implementation?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

[Here](https://www.codechef.com/problems/URCALC) is the link to the problem
It's relatively easy looking problem with simple logic, of making your own calculator.
You input two numbers and character any of these four('+', '-', '*', '/') and output the answer.

So I wrote my code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a, b, d;
    char c;
    
    cin>>a>>b;
    cin>>c;
    
if(c=='+') cout<<a+b;
if(c=='-') cout<<a-b;
if(c=='*') cout<<a*b;
if(c=='/') cout<<setprecision(10)<<(float)a/b;
    return 0;
}
```

But it wasn't able to pass all the test cases. I tweaked a bit with code line of division and looked up other people's submission and found out correct answer as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a, b, d;
    char c;
    
    cin>>a>>b;
    cin>>c;
    
if(c=='+') cout<<a+b;
if(c=='-') cout<<a-b;
if(c=='*') cout<<a*b;
if(c=='/') cout<<setprecision(10)<<1.0*a/b; //here is the change
    return 0;
}
```

so I wasn't able to understand what kind of input gives different output to above both codes

Difference between these two lines:

```
if(c=='/') cout<<setprecision(10)<<(float)a/b;
if(c=='/') cout<<setprecision(10)<<1.0*a/b;
```

Comment: `1.0` is a `double` literal

Comment: I am curious why you wrote `(float)a/b` initially. Why did you apply the cast? both `a` and `b` are already `float`.

Comment: In terms of implementing the assignment, `double a, b, d;` probably makes the most sense, and get rid of all the other chicanery.

Comment: `1.0*a/b` is kind of like `(double)a/b` (and may optimize to the same thing).  So the two code snippets are not comparing apples-to-apples.

Comment: You can write ```1.0*a/b``` and ```1.0f*a/b``` to see again the difference. The latter will give a result like what you see with ```(float)a/b```

Comment: Most of the code in the question is irrelevant. Remove `c` and the tests that depend on it, and the calculations that don't involve division. All that matters is `cout<<setprecision(10)<<1.0*a/b;` and `cout<<setprecision(10)<<1.0*a/b;` (both of which should insert a `'\n'` at the end). Initialize `a` and `b` to values that show the problem.

Comment: There is also a sublety, since `a/b` has type `float` and `1.0*a/b` has type `double` that the two (for some values of `a` and `b`) do not compare equal, which also means that `cout<<setprecision(10)<<(float)a/b` and `cout<<setprecision(10)<<1.0*a/b` can produce different output.     The "correct" answer described by the OP is (effectively) requiring division to be done in `double` precision.   An exercise that requires input to be of type `float`, but to do *some* operations in `double` precision, is a bit fishy.

Comment: *But it wasn't able to pass all the test cases.* -- I do not recommend attempting to solve questions on those sites that have anything to do with floating point calculations.  Why?  Because floating point is not exact.  Let's say that the website has an answer of "4.123456789" and your answer is "4.123456788".  Are you going to try and figure out why that least significant digit is off by 1?   If you are going to use those "competitive coding" sites, stick to questions that have integer-based questions and solutions.

Comment: learning how to read the compiled code can help.  for example, https://godbolt.org/z/dqMh3Wa5Y contains the relevant parts of your code and a couple of other variants.  hovering over the instructions on the right shows where single precision (i.e. IEEE754 32bit binary floats on x86 architecture) vs double precision operations are used

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that `1.0*a/b` creates a double (as `1.0` is a double) while `(float)a/b` creates a `float` that has less precision.

Also you can use `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` to know how many digits you need in base 10 to represent a number without loss. You'll notice that for `float` and `double` you have:

- `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 == 6` which is less than your required precision (10)
- `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 == 15` which is more than your required precision (10)

For more information about the precision you can check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that:

- `(float) a / b` is converting `a` to `float`, and performing a division between `a` and `b`. This is actually unnecessary, because `a` and `b` are already declared as `float`, so you could have just as well written `a / b`
- `1.0 * a / b` is multiplying `a` with `1.0` and `1.0` is a `double` literal. This means that both `a` and `b` will be converted to double precision types before the division, and the result of the division will have double precision too.

The latter expression could have been written as `(double) a / b` as well. If `double` is an IEEE-754 floating-point number, then multiplication with `1.0` is a no-op, i.e. an operation that does nothing.
The only effect of multiplying with `1.0` is that the other side gets converted to `double` if it's a `float`.

Another solution is to declare all the variables as `double`:

```cpp
double a, b, d;
```

If you need more precision, it's usually best to use the same level of precision everywhere, not just for one operation.

Answer (score 0):

In your original program these expressions

```
(float)a/b
```

and

```
a/b
```

are equivalent because the both expressions have the type `float` due to the type of the operands.

This expression

```
1.0*a/b
```

has the type `double` due to the constant `1.0` of the type `double`. So the result is more precised.

Try the following demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 = "
        << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10
        << '\n';

    std::cout << "std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 = "
        << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10
        << '\n';
}
```

Its output might look like

```
std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 = 6
std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 = 15
```

As you can see objects of the type `double` can be represented more accurately with more digits.

You could write instead like

```
( double )a/b
```

or

```
static_cast<double>( a )/b
```

to get the same result. Or you could initially declare the variables as having the type `double`.

```
double a, b;
```

You need also to check whether the variable `b` is not equal to zero before performing the calculation.

Pay attention to that in the both programs the variable `d` is not used and may be removed.